# Using AmCharts.makeChart V3 - Not getting new INDIA MAP including POK

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, amcharts

I have a client's website where their developer used AmCharts.makeChart version 3. However, the client is asking about the new political India map. Not sure if AmChart ver 4 has that.

Can anyone help please?

The code in the customized PHP template goes like this

```
var map = AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv",{
type: "map",
theme: "dark",
projection: "mercator",
panEventsEnabled : true,
backgroundColor : "#F1F1F1",
backgroundAlpha : 1,
zoomControl: {
zoomControlEnabled : true
},
dataProvider : {
map : "worldHigh",
getAreasFromMap : true,
areas :
[
    {
        "id": "IN",
        "showAsSelected": true
    },
```

Comment: v3 maps are no longer updated as it is approaching its EOL this year. v4 maps are being actively updated.

Comment: Thank you. I needed some help if updating this code in v4.
I can't write code. Hence asking.

Comment: I recommend looking at the [map documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/) as there are plenty of basic examples there. Information on how to use a country-specific world maps, such as India's, can be found [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/country-specific-world-maps/).